# Django-admin error: no such table auth_user

Tags: python, django

I am trying to login to my sites admin panel. However it always throws `no such table: auth_user`.

There are neither migrations to apply nor changes detected to migrate.
I have no forms/models yet in my application, I just installed Django-admin.

I also tried it by reinstalling django-admin, without success.

Any solution to this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 100, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 140, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1151, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\CFD\CFD>py manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\CFD\CFD>py manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\CFD\CFD>
```

**Settings.py:**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # other Apps
    'calculator',

    # adding six because of dependency problem with Django 3
    'six',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

[...]

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: did you create superuser yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it to work.

1. remove `db.sqlite3` from the DATABASES/Name
2. remove your db.sqlite file in the project dir
3. add `db.sqlite3` again to the DATABASES/Name
4. run `$ py manage.py migrate`
5. create superuser again `$ py manage.py createsuperuser`
6. log into admin panel

Comment: I think problem was that you did not run `py manage.py createsuperuser` before?